# how to open generated excel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, export-to-excel

I am exporting data from sql server database to excel in wpf, and I have achieved the function successully. Now I want to open the generated excel automatically after I save it to a certain location. Any ideas? Thanks in advance. My desired function is like that in the screenshot: [image: My desired function]

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = null;
        string data = null;
       // string path = null;
        //string myfilename = "Report";
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        //xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();

        xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        xlWorkSheet.Name = "Customer List";

        //connectionString = "data source=servername;initial catalog=databasename;user id=username;password=password;";
        //SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
        cnn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=ClientLists;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        cnn.Open();
        sql = "select FirstName, LastName, City, PostCode, TelephoneNo from Customers";
        SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dscmd.Fill(ds);


        for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count -1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count -1; j++)
            {
                data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = data;
            }
        }


         xlWorkSheet.Cells.ColumnWidth = 16;
         xlWorkSheet.Cells.Font.Size = 12; 
         xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1].Font.Bold = true;
         xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2].Font.Bold = true;
         xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3].Font.Bold = true;
         xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4].Font.Bold = true;
         xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 5].Font.Bold = true;
         xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1].Font.Color = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbBlue;
         xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2].Font.Color = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbBlue;
         xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3].Font.Color = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbBlue;
         xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4].Font.Color = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbBlue;
         xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 5].Font.Color = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbBlue;
         xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "First Name";
         xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Last Name";
         xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "City";
         xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Post Code";
         xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Telephone NO";          

        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();


        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);

    }

    private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the SaveAs function by adding the following code: System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog oDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog(); oDialog.Filter = "Excel files | *.xls"; if (oDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) { sFileName = oDialog.FileName; }